# about react javascript grammar const syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { ImageButton } from '../Button';

type AddEmojiButtonPropTypes = {
  small?: boolean,
  children?: any, // eslint-disable-line react/require-default-props
};

const AddEmojiButton = ({
  small,
  children,
  ...other
}: AddEmojiButtonPropTypes) => (
  <ImageButton
    type="button"
    {...other}
  >
    {small ? (
      <img
        alt="Add Emoji"
        src="https://res.cloudinary.com/df9jsefb9/image/upload/c_scale,h_54,q_auto/v1503278075/assets/btn-add-emoji_3x.png"
        srcSet="
          https://res.cloudinary.com/df9jsefb9/image/upload/c_scale,h_108,q_auto/v1503278075/assets/btn-add-emoji_3x.png 2x,
          https://res.cloudinary.com/df9jsefb9/image/upload/c_scale,h_162,q_auto/v1503278075/assets/btn-add-emoji_3x.png 3x
        "
      />
    ) : (
      <img
        alt="Add Emoji"
        src="https://res.cloudinary.com/df9jsefb9/image/upload/s--nnCHGEWM--/c_scale,h_110,q_auto/v1502250483/assets/group-2-copy-3_3x.png"
        srcSet="
          https://res.cloudinary.com/df9jsefb9/image/upload/s--nnCHGEWM--/c_scale,h_220,q_auto/v1502250483/assets/group-2-copy-3_3x.png 2x,
          https://res.cloudinary.com/df9jsefb9/image/upload/s--nnCHGEWM--/c_scale,h_330,q_auto/v1502250483/assets/group-2-copy-3_3x.png 3x,
        "
      />
    )}
  </ImageButton>
);


AddEmojiButton.defaultProps = {
  small: false,
};

AddEmojiButton.propTypes = {
  small: PropTypes.bool,
};

export default AddEmojiButton;
```

The const declaration does not understand well among the JavaScript source that I attached above.

```
const AddEmojiButton = ({
  small,
  children,
 ...other
}: AddEmojiButtonPropTypes) => (
  <ImageButton
```

In the above code, can you tell us what the {} in the const declaration means and what the: operator means?

Normally when declaring an object with const or var

```
const foo = {
  name: 'foo'
  age: 30,
  gender: 'male'
  func1 : (e) => {}
}
```

I know there is a declaration like this, but I wonder why there is only a property name of props and no value.

In addition

```
({small,childeren,...other} : AddEmojiButtonPropTypes) => ImageButton
```

What does this form mean?

I wonder if the original JavaScript syntax is the correct expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
({small,childeren,...other} : AddEmojiButtonPropTypes) => ImageButton
```

3 dots is spread attribute ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)), it's come from es6 spread. Reactjs using spread for dynamic props, see [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes). So if you take a look like this

```
const AddEmojiButton = ({
  small,
  children,
  ...other
}: AddEmojiButtonPropTypes) => <ImageButton type="button" {...other} />
```

actually parse `other`, example has object `width` and `height`, it will become :

```
const other = { witdh: "100", height: "100"};

<ImageButton type="button" width="100" height="100" />
```

see [repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=C4TwDgpgBAggJnAogWwPYCsCWAhArsYVAOwAUAnVMAFXAgGcoBeKAbwCgoo7kBDAGz4B-AFxQARqlR8IPIgBoOUAMYALTHzhkIREVFkg5UAPRGo9PpiLAAtHEx0eY6dYtFoWnkuBGtAR1yYWrYQAGY8uHw2YBRgdGwAvgDcbGxKxHTAsAgoGDj4hERMUAAU7Jyc3Px8CuXKahpa8oqcAHRtqMAqEGQJAJRMAHxQADwAkrwA5hB4BMRQoJCMAERi-cRLrG0tHV1k8cYDiUA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Creact%2Cstage-1&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)